# Dart json encode map with custom object as key

Tags: json, dart

I have started working with dart . I have the following scenario. In my application I have a Map which has a Peptide object as key for every entry and a num as value .

I am trying to encode this map as json but I get
`Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:2`

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Peptide {
  String name;
  Peptide({required this.name});
}

void main() {
  Map<Peptide, num> foo = {Peptide(name: "a"): 0.5, Peptide(name: "b"): 0.3};
  print(json.encode(foo));
}
```

Any ideas how can I approach this issue?

Comment: The key in json has to be a string

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Peptide {
  String name;
  Peptide({required this.name});
}

void main() {
  Peptide peptide = Peptide(name: "peter");
  Peptide peptide1 = Peptide(name: "john");
  Map<String, dynamic> foo = {
   "names" : [
     {peptide.name : 0.5},
     {peptide1.name : 0.7}
       ]
    };
  print(json.encode(foo));
}
```

Which would give:

```
{"names":[{"peter":0.5},{"john":0.7}]}
```

---

Another way would be:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Peptide {
  String name;
  double num;
  Peptide({required this.name,required this.num});
  
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'num' : num
    };
  }
}

void main() {
  Peptide peptide = Peptide(name: "peter",num: 0.5);
  Peptide peptide1 = Peptide(name: "john", num: 0.7);
  Map<String, dynamic> foo = {
   "names" : [
      peptide.toMap(),
      peptide1.toMap()
       ]
    };
  print(json.encode(foo));
}
```

which would give you:

```
{"names":[{"name":"peter","num":0.5},{"name":"john","num":0.7}]}
```

Check this:

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json